# Android services being stopped very soon unless I draw over other apps

Tags: java, android, service, android-service

My app run from Android 5.0+. I am currently testing my app on a Android 9 device.
I have a service that acts as a client.
I have tried starting the service with both `startService` and `startForeground` but it didn't change the outcome (I didn't display any notification in the status bar though). I've noticed that those Services who also draw over other apps won't be killed after few minutes, instead services that only execute background code are being stopped shortly after. Why is that?